# how to update post date without timepart in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-update, date-arithmetic

I want to change date only without the timestamp part. I'm trying to change from phpMyAdmin. So it doesn't execute 3 parameters of DATEDIFF.

For e.g:

| post_date |
| --- |
| 2020-12-16 23:20:48 |
| 2020-12-16 23:40:42 |

Add 4 days

| post_date |
| --- |
| 2020-12-20 23:20:48 |
| 2020-12-20 23:40:42 |

**OR** Change date to current date (Today is 28th of December 2020)

| post_date |
| --- |
| 2020-12-28 23:20:48 |
| 2020-12-28 23:40:42 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adjust it with an interval:

```sql
UPDATE post
SET    post_date = DATE_ADD(post_date, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```

Comment: perfect!
Could you help with last opt like I need to change all dates to today's date?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to translate the stored date to today's date, you can do:

```
update mytable 
set post_date = addtime(current_date, time(post_date))
```

Or using string operations:

```
update mytable 
set post_date = concat(current_date, ' ', time(post_date))
```

The other question is just simple date arithmetics. You can add 4 days to a date by adding an interval, like:

```
update mytable 
set post_date = post_date + interval 4 day
```

Comment: let me know if I can manually enter date.

Comment: @dgrtkhan09: sure. You just replace `current_date` with your literal date.

Comment: I replaced `current_date` to `'2020-12-25'` but it changed timestamp too 00:00:00 ..